# Rotas em angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routes

Estou estudando rotas no angular e seguindo um tutorial do site deles.Eles pedem para criar um app-routing.module com o *ng generate module app-routing --flat --module=app* no cmd, meu código para de funcionar quando eu coloco a tag  no app.component.html

**app-routing.module:**

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes/heroes.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-messages></app-messages>
```

E consegui fazer com que funcionasse mas pra isso tive que mudar o **app-routing.module** e ficou assim:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import{ HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent}
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

e tive que mudar o **app.module.ts**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import { routing } from './app-routing.module';//<-coloquei isso

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    MessagesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    routing//<-coloquei isso
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Eu encontrei diversos tutoriais com a solução que não funciona e achei alguns poucos com a solução que funcionou, então minha pergunta é:

- porque a segunda solução funciona e a primeira não?
- porque que existem tantos lugares mostrando a solução errada?
- existe uma maneira melhor de criar essas rotas?

Answer (score 1):

Se vc preferir, vc pode fazer diretamente no ng.module:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'registrar', component: RegistrarComponent },
];
```

Imports:

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
        appRoutes,
        { useHash: true, enableTracing: true }
    ),
],
```

E no app.component.html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="content-wrapper">
       <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </div>
</div>
```